# Yii Php, PostgreSQL - programmatically handling whitespaces in database

Tags: php, postgresql, yii, whitespace, criteria

i'm having a trouble with handling various, database values, special characters etc.

I'm using **Yii** php, specifically **CDbCriteria** when querying the postgres database, and i'm having problems with entries that have white spaces before and after the entry, to demonstrate:

I have:

```
  $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
  $criteria->compare('first_name',trim($name) , false, 'OR'); 
  $criteria->compare('surname', trim($name), false, 'OR');

  $person = Name::model()->find($criteria);
```

The code above is suppose to find in the database, a matched row, given the $name variable from an input form. This works perfectly if the **first_name or surname** in the database table has **no white spaces**.

for example:

```
$name = "Richard";
```

But in the database, the first_name value is:

**"[white space]Richard[whitespace]"**

Then the the $person will return null, because "Richard" cannot be found since the **'Richard' with white spaces** is in the database. However the proper behavior is that it should match correctly for they are basically the same name ( i do know that having whitespaces in the database is not a good thing, for every entry should be trimmed, however the application should be flexible enough to handle this). How do i solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices

1) programatically remove white space when you edit a record (look at `beforeSave()`)

2) use TRIM in the criteria.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition = "TRIM(first_name) = '".trim($name)."' or TRIM(surname) = '".trim($name)."'";
```

You may be able to do the above as `$criteria->compare("TRIM(first_name)"...)` - but I am not sure.

Comment: That was fast.. the $criteria->compare("TRIM ..works..i preferred no. 2..thank you

Comment: @YiiNewbie You better implement first one for many reasons, but mainly because of it is a good thing to keep your data consistent.